# UILabel question

Tags: iphone, uilabel

Is this possible to achieve something like that on iOS simply using UILabel + UIView ?

I've tried using a UIWebView but it's too slow to be used in a UITableView.

[That style using UILabel ? http://cl.ly/f9d4f776171e1cb6faaf/content](http://cl.ly/f9d4f776171e1cb6faaf/content)

Comment: You want 1 label or 2 labels?

Comment: I don't mind. I think that one way to do it is using two label.
The only thing is that the NSString that I want to display is not always the same length.

Comment: I don't get your idea. You want to display a Text with textColor is white and background is red?

Comment: But still I know that two lines is maximum.

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737092/objective-c-uilabel-multiline-vertical-gap-height

Comment: @vodkhang I have the NSString @"This a test for iOS and I like it" and I want to display two labels. But the length of the NSString changes.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
lbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Assuming lbl is a UILabel object.

Comment: This will add a rectangle red background. Not exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
lbl.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
```

Comment: If you want to make such a text, you need to set it like this, (change text color, back ground color and font size). 

lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
lbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
lbl.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];

IF the string is not of same length, you can set the Font Size in IB to "Adjust to fit", or 
lbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth  = YES
OR, you can change the label frame size with string size. You can get the current string length in pixel using NSString.sizeWithFont method in UIKit framework.