# How to change the Vertical Margin / Gap in UILabel line

Tags: ios, nsstring, uilabel, margin, drawrect

I'm looking for a way to decrease the line gap in a multiline UILabel.

This seems to be sort of mentioned here [Objective C - UILabel multiline vertical gap height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737092/objective-c-uilabel-multiline-vertical-gap-height).

But I wanted to be clear, before reinventing the wheel:

See Here for example [image: How it's done in Photoshop]

Any ideas or thoughts would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do that with UILabel, but you can use [MSLabel](https://github.com/LemonCake/MSLabel)